# Cassandra - nodetool rebuild

Tags: cassandra, rebuild

Adding a new DC to a 3 node cluster. The data in the existing 3 nodes is very small 10GB. 
Executed following steps to add new DC.

```
1) Updated new cluster config with following Cassandra.yml parameter   
    a. Auto_bootstrap: false    
    b. Seeds: - Matched the seeds with the current seed config.     
2) Started the new cluster    
3) Update the keyspace in DC to add the new DC    
    a. ALTER KEYSPACE "temp" WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'clu-1':3, 'newclu-1' : 3};    
4) Started “nodetool rebuild --- my_cluster”  in all nodes at the new DC.
```

Am I missing any steps. The reason is the cluster stopped sending the data. I see following line on all the nodes.

```
INFO  [STREAM-IN-/] 2017-05-24 18:36:26,337  StreamResultFuture.java:212 - [Stream #e482eed0-40af-11e7-8d18-21388e2034a2] All sessions completed
```

But when I do "nodetool netstats". The rebuild is still running.

```
Mode: NORMAL
Rebuild d4f4d160-40b2-11e7-87d8-ed7164988f34
Read Repair Statistics:
Attempted: 300
Mismatch (Blocking): 0
Mismatch (Background): 0
Pool Name Active Pending Completed
Commands n/a 0 218172
Responses n/a 0 921087
```

Even the nodetool status on the new nodes just show few MB data vs 10GB.

Comment: What was your snitch before and after adding a new Data center? What is your Cassandra version?